# Can I apply a style to all pseudo selectors in CSS or Sass?

Tags: css, css-selectors, sass

Is it possible apply style to all of an anchor tag's **pseudo selectors** with CSS or Sass?

Something like

```css
a:* {
    color: #900;  
}
```

instead of

```css
a {
    &:hover, &:link, &:active, &:visited {
        color: #900; 
    } 
}
```

I just want to reset standard styling. In CSS, the wildcard can be used to apply styles to all elements... but how about to all pseudo-selectors?

Comment: There is no universal pseudo-class selector or anything like that. If there was, it would match not just your four link pseudo-classes, but everything else defined in CSS, which doesn't really make any sense.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Short Answer**: No, not directly

---

However, a mixin could be used to have a similar effect.

```
// Sets the style only for pseudo selectors
@mixin setLinkSelectorStyle {
  &:hover, &:link, &:active, &:visited {
        @content;
    }
}

// Sets the style to pseudo selectors AND base default anchor
@mixin setLinkStyleAll {
  &, &:hover, &:link, &:active, &:visited {
        @content;
    }
}

a {
  color:red;
  @include setLinkSelectorStyle {
    color:gold;
  }
}

a.specialLink {
  @include setLinkStyleAll {
    color:purple;
  }
}
```

---

[Example using http://sassmeister.com/ compiled SASS]

```css
a {
  color: red;
}
a:hover, a:link, a:active, a:visited {
  color: gold;
}

a.specialLink, a.specialLink:hover, a.specialLink:link, a.specialLink:active, a.specialLink:visited {
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<a>Normal anchor, No href (:link won't work, but other selectors will)</a>
<hr />
<a href="#">Normal anchor</a>
<hr />
<a class="specialLink">Specific class (no href)</a>
<hr />
<a class="specialLink" href="#">Specific class</a>
```

The mixins will create a rule for all the pseudo selectors when the mixin is included on the anchor / class.

---

Removed old answer, look at history to see it.

Comment: I just want apply one color for several link states. Your solution is what I'm looking for.

Comment: It may be what you need, but it doesn't answer the question

Comment: @GustavoSiqueira The answer to my knowledge is no, as I say at the top of my answer as a note, and slightly towards the end. So I simply offered an alternative that I have used before and hoped would help others.

Comment: Updated answer; hopefully it now "answers" the question, instead of offering a very poor hack.

Answer (score 1):

U can do it like that:

```
  &:before, &:after {
      content: 'a';
  }
```